# Grouping together query counts into as few queries as possible in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm not a database expert but I've inherited this SQLite database I have to work with. It contains tags, images and events. An event contains a number of images and an image contains a number of tags (the tags describe the image content e.g. coffee, phone, laptop, etc.).

The table structure looks something like this:

```
row_id      tags          image_id          event_id

1           computer     1                 1
2           desk         1                 1
3           chair        1                 1

4           computer     2                 1
5           coffee       2                 1
6           desk         2                 1

7           dog          3                 2
8           phone        3                 2

etc.        etc.         etc.              etc.     // many 1000's
```

The users of our system used to search for images by choosing some tags and we had a very simple query which returned a ranked list favoring images containing the most tags. It looked like this:

```
SELECT image_id
FROM TagsTable
WHERE tags 
IN ('computer', 'desk', 'chair') // user variables
GROUP BY image_id
ORDER BY COUNT(image_id) DESC
```

But now we want to return a list of the events (which I need to rank) instead of individual images. I can achieve this by doing many queries in a loop but it's very slow. Ideally I'm trying to produce the following information in as few queries as possible.

So if the user searched for 'computer', 'desk' and 'chair', you would get...

```
event_id    computer_count      desk_count     chair_count    event_image_count    
1           12                  15             9              56                   
2           22                  0              13             24                   
3           14                  7              0              32
etc.        etc.                etc.           etc.           etc.

// no results if all tag counts are 0
```

So at a glance we can see event 1 contains a total of 56 images and the tag 'computer' appears 12 times, 'desk' appears 15 times and 'chair' appears 9 times.

Is this possible using just SQL or do I need to perform multiple queries? Please note I am using SQLite.

Comment: So since I'm using SQLite, I'm stuck pulling out appropriate counts in a big loop?

Comment: "So since I'm using SQLite, I'm stuck pulling out appropriate counts in a big loop?" The "hardcoded" pivot version like @GordonLinoff answer is possible in SQLite indeed.. You can't make a dynamic pivot version because SQLite does not support dynamic SQL preparing and execution..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can answer this specific question using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT event_id,
       SUM(CASE WHEN tags = 'computer' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as computer_count,
       SUM(CASE WHEN tags = 'desk' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as desk_count,
       SUM(CASE WHEN tags = 'chair' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as chair_count,
       COUNT(DISTINCT image_id) as image_count
FROM TagsTable
WHERE tags IN ('computer', 'desk', 'chair') 
GROUP BY event_id;
```

EDIT:

To add an "average" column:

```
SELECT . . .
       SUM(CASE WHEN tags IN ('computer', 'desk', 'chair') THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END) / 3 as tag_average
```

Comment: @AzzyDude you might want to use `LOWER(tags)` instead off `tags`.. `LOWER(tags)` also correcly handles tags which start with a capital letter

Comment: Is it possible to easily create a final column which adds computer_count, desk_count and chair_count up and divides by 3? My knowledge of what SQLite can achieve is limited.